# Is it inappropriate to email a new Employer's Team lead to ask him to be on his team

Tags: job-offer

The back story is that I interviewed for a company and I got a job offer.

They told me everyone that interviewed me wants me on their team, so they are going to have conversations about which team I should be on and then get feedback from me on the decision.

After accepting the offer I started looking around on the companies GitHub and found the profile of team director for what my ideal team would be at this new company.

My question is: is it inappropriate for me to email and say that I will be starting at the end of May and that I was told I would have some say over the team I want to be on and that I want to be on his team.

Edit: I have been working with a recruiter for this process, should I go through him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that to directly email the director is not a good idea. It looks like you're going "around" the system in order to whisper in their ear. However, since you mentioned that you're in contact with a recruiter, and presumably that recruiter is the one who told you everyone wants you, I don't think it would hurt to send an email to them saying essentially "If it helps your decision, I have a specific interest in Team X". Maybe your suggestion will be taken into account, or maybe it will be ignored, but I think this is the best midway-point to not burn any bridges while still putting your preference out there.

Comment: I really like this approach. I think this is probably the approach I will take. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that it's highly inappropriate.    You were hired by the company, and the individual managers probably have very little say on it at this point. They may be hiring to fill out another manager's team, and they may be offended if you express a desire to be on another team.  The result may be to alienate your future manager.

A caveat:   If they have their discussion and come back to ask you for your input, then it's appropriate, perhaps even good to be able to say you did your research.   But I'd wait to see if they give you that choice.    I've got a feeling that they probably are "going to discuss it", meaning that they'll likely try to decide which team needs someone most.   I'd be careful of putting your foot in your mouth by stating too emphatically which team you don't want to work on, or communicating you don't want to work for the guy that you'd very possibly be working for.

Comment: That is a great answer Keith thank you for that. I am glad that I asked before taking the action. I was leaning this way but I really want to work on the mentioned directors team. Thanks, again.